# Angular cdkScrollable ViewChild is undefined

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-cdk, viewchild

I'm trying to listen to scroll event on an element of my template thanks to cdkScrollable.

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild(CdkScrollable, {static: false})
public scrollable: CdkScrollable;

...

public ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.scrollable.subscribe(this.scrollDetected)
}
```

Template:

```
<pre
  cdk-scrollable
  #fareNotes
  [innerHTML]="changeFareNotes">
</pre>
```

However, this.scrollable is always undefined.

If I try to define the ViewChild as follow, it exists, but only gets the ElementRef type (with only nativeElement property but not the scrollable() method).

```
 @ViewChild('fareNotes', {static: false})
 public fareNotes: CdkScrollable;
```

Comment: the directive is `cdkScrollable`, not `cdk-scrollable`.

Comment: I had tried both but there is zero difference :/

Comment: Actually, the cdk-scrollable  attribute is also possible according to their docs. Did you import the ScrollingModule?

Comment: in the second query for @ViewChild, you could try @ViewChild('fareNotes', {read: CdkScrollable}) public fareNotes:CdkScrollable;

Comment: Thks guys. Both comments helped! Answered my own question if it can help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So:

1. I was missing the ScrollingModule in my module declaration (I only had the CdkScrollable import in my script). I would have expected to get an error for missing this type of thing.
2. And then, it's either:

   - the generic CdkScrollable ViewChild: 
     @ViewChild(CdkScrollable, {static: false}) public scrollable: CdkScrollable;
   - or this syntax to access by selector:
     @ViewChild('fareNotes', {read: CdkScrollable}) public fareNotes:CdkScrollable;

Credits go to David Fontes and andreivictor for the helpfull comments.